# mysql querying to combine two columns in a table

Tags: mysql

I want to query like this :

Suppose if you have a table like where X and Y are columns.

```
X Y

A 1
B 2
C 3
D 4
```

and now you want to create something like:

```
X Y Z
A 1 2
B 2 3
C 3 4
D 4 5
```

Basically you want to create a pair with the next row value here. The pairs are (Y, Z) like (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4). How will I write mysql query for something like this ? Any pointers?

Comment: How are you going to determine the "next" row? Just the literal next row in the table, or the next row sorted by some values?

Comment: Assuming there is an auto-increment `id` field governing row order in your table, in the case of `('D', 4)` there is no next row value. How come `Z = 5` for this case?

Comment: Don't go into auto increment, the pairing has to be done with the next row only.

Comment: SQL tables are unordered sets, there is no inherent row order in them. Hence you need at least one row (auto-increment or not) so as to define row order. The OP has not provided one yet.

Answer (score 2):

From what I see, the value of Z is `1+value of Y`.

Have a look at this simple query :-

```
SELECT x,y,(y+1) AS Z from test
```

**SQL Fiddle :-**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08b1e/2

[image]

Comment: You are supposed to take the next row not just increment. Pairing has to be with the next row.

Comment: The next row can be increment of 1 or n.

Comment: That is easy as well. However, OP gave such a values which made me think of this solution. Let's wait for him.

Comment: Actually I gave this problem to OP :)

Comment: @RakeshRanjanSukla
Haha ok, I'll update my solution then.

Comment: @RakeshRanjanSukla
I don't understand how this trail will end then. Because for the last row, there'd be nothing to pair up with.

Comment: Its fine if it can't pair up

Comment: You do need to have an auto-increment column here.